# How do I indent a shape from an SVG file into the face of a cube (ie to make gaming dice)?

Tags: faces, extrude, svg

I am creating a dice for a board game, which needs to have a different icon indented into the surface of each face.

I have icon files in SVG format and have tried to import these to blender, and have converted them from curves to meshes. I then snapped them to the surface of the dice cube. I tried to use the extrude function on the Edit mode by entering Edit mode with both the icon and cube selected. This partially works but simply creates a subsurface extension of the shape, leaving the face of the dice unchanged.

How do I simply push an indent into the cube, as though pressing a shape into a block of clay, using the SVG shapes?

Or, more abstractly, how do I create a new, non square, face on a surface based on a shape, sourced from SVG or otherwise?

Comment: hello, could you please show some pictures, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: A couple of test files are here at https://pasteall.org/blend/89baf9b9f1a04162a18d47fe8fc378da and https://pasteall.org/blend/b79fa9717ead4236965e70077ed21a52

Comment: for you circular arrow for example you can use boolean to indent your dice, just recalculate the normals of your arrow first

Comment: for your round dice, you could do the same, but the topology is a bit messy, you should clean it. Do you plan to 3D print or is it just for pictures?

Comment: Thanks! I am pretty new to blender, so I'm not really sure how to do a boolean indent (I think this is equivalent to the Boolean functions on illustrator and is what I was trying to do), or recalculate normals. Or to clean the topography :D.  Yes, I plan to 3D print it, really all I wanted to do was round off the edges slightly so it's more dice like...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Boolean* modifier to indent your shapes.

First recalculate the normals of your icon objects (they are flipped and the *Boolean* won't work, so in *Edit* mode select all and Shift <kbd>N</kbd>). You can simplify the icons with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* but the current topology seems ok. Extrude it on Z:

[image]

You can display it as wireframe. Move your icon a bit downwards so that it penetrates your dice.:

[image]

Give your dice a *Boolean* modifier with the icon as *Target*. You don't have to tweak the options, keep the *Difference* mode:

[image]

Apply the modifier, move away the icon object.

[image]

The topology of this dice is bad though:

[image]

You should better redo it from scratch, maybe a boolean between a cube and a sphere:

[image]

Or bevel the 6 vertices of a cube:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wonder if you could just clarify though, "Give your dice a Boolean modifier with the icon as Target. Apply the modifier, move away the icon object." I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that - there are a few options on the Boolean modifier selector and I'm not able to recreate what you have done here. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I've edited my answer, you don't have to tweak the modifier's options.